# Getting a REST API error of "A pair of repeating parameter value lists were passed to an AMP HTTPPost function but the lists to not match."

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, sms, httppost

I've tried two different REST API calls and they seem to work in Postman, but not when I set it up on my own.  Same error for both so I'm guessing it's something simple I'm doing wrong.

Full error -> Exception occurred: A pair of repeating parameter value lists were passed to an AMP HTTPPost function but the lists to not match. Parameter list pairs must have a matching number of items in each list. Parameter List 1: [null] Parameter List 2: item count = 1

Thanks for any help!

Here's the code I'm using which returns a token:

````
<script runat="server">

 Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
  var addSubToExtKey = "data extension key";
 function getAccessToken() {
   var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('lookupDE','subscriberKey','0035A99993ezdapQAA');
   if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
    var payload = '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxx","account_id":"xxxxxxxxxx"}';
     
     var authurl = 'https://{{subdomain}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
     var contentType = 'application/json';
     
     //var response = HTTP.Post(authurl, contentType, payload);
     var content=[0];
     var statusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(authurl, contentType, payload,[],[], content);
     Write("REST API Access Token Request: "+"<br>");
     //Write("Status Code: "+response.StatusCode+"<br>");
     //Write("Response: "+response.Response+"<br>");
     
     return Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content[0]);
   } else {
    Write("I'm sorry we can't find your account please contact your account representative"+"<br><br>");
   }
 }
  
  try{
   var jsonresp = getAccessToken();
    var authToken = jsonresp.access_token;
    var restURL = jsonresp.rest_instance_url;
    //Write(authToken);
    //Write(restURL);
    
    //var payloadUpsert = '{"contact_key":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","email": "test@test.com","phone": "11231231"}';
    var payload = '{"subscribers":[{"mobilenumber": "11231231","subscriberkey": "ddddddddddd"}],"shortCode" : "12345","messageText" : "OPTINNOW"}';
    
    var apiroute, bearertoken
    
    apiroute = restURL + 'hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:'+addSubToExtKey+'/rowset';
    apirouteSMS = restURL + 'sms/v1/queueMO';
    bearertoken = 'Bearer '+ authToken;
    
    var headerName = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = [bearertoken];
    var restContent = [0];
    //var restResponse = HTTP.Post(apiroute, "application/json", payloadUpsert, headerNames, headerValues);
    var restStatusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(apirouteSMS, "application/json", payload, headerNames, headerValues, restContent);
    Write("Triggered Send POST Request:"+"<br>");
    Write(restStatusCode);
    Write(restContent[0]);
  }
  catch(e) {
   Write("Exception occurred: "+e+"<br>");
  }

</script>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily and Sadly, the issues is as simple as a missing `s` in your variable name.

You have the variable declared as `headerName`

```
var headerName = ["Authorization"];
```

But inside of your HTTPPost call, you have utilized the variable as `headerNames`

```
var restStatusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(apirouteSMS, "application/json", payload, headerNames, headerValues, restContent);
```

Because of this, `headerNames` is returning null (as shown in your error) while `headerValues` is showing your token. This mismatches values to names, which tosses your error.

So by changing either `headerName` to `headerNames` or vice versa should resolve your issue.

Comment: Ugh.... but thank you!

Comment: @ErikB - Happens to me all the time, which is the only reason I knew what to look for lol